# how to insert record in multiple table in codeingiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following form. The form basically comprises two portion, one portion is for basic details and a second one is for the features, Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Form </title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <h1>property Detail</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> City </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="city"> </td>

          <td> Location </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="location"> </td>

          <td> Marlas </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="marlas"> </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> Possesion
            <input type="radio" name="feature" value="possesion">
          </td>
          <td> Possesion1
            <input type="radio" name="feature" value="possesion1">
          </td>
          <td> Possesion2
            <input type="radio" name="feature" value="possesion2">
          </td>
          <td> Possesion3
            <input type="radio" name="feature" value="possesion3">
          </td>
          <td> Possesion4
            <input type="radio" name="feature" value="possesion4">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>    
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I have two tables in my database, one is a detail which has this column(id, city, location, marlas) and second is a feature which has column(id, property_id, feature). I want my basic detail goes into detail table and feature goes in the feature table. 
so far my basic detail is going into detail table but how I can insert feature into feature table.

here is my **controller**:

```
function property()
{
  if($_POST)
  {
    $data= array ( 'city' => $_POST['city'], 'location' => $_POST['location'],
      'marlas' => $_POST['marlas'] );
    $data['var']= $this->Mdata->p_detail($data);
  }
}
```

and here is my **model**:

```
function p_detail($data){
  $this->db->insert('detail',$data);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: make another insert function to insert in other table

Comment: is it good practice to make another function ??

Comment: also, you can pass all the data in `p_detail` function and then you can insert into 2 separate tables

Comment: i pass the basic data in p_detail through array, how i can pass the feature data ??

Comment: function p_detail($data){
  $this->db->insert('detail',$data);
$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$update_data = $data;
$update_data['last_id'] = $last_id ;
 $this->db->insert('detail1',$update_data);

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Form:**

```
<tr>
  <td> Possesion
    <input type="radio" name="feature[]" value="possesion">
  </td>
  <td> Possesion1
    <input type="radio" name="feature[]" value="possesion1">
  </td>
  <td> Possesion2
    <input type="radio" name="feature[]" value="possesion2">
  </td>
  <td> Possesion3
    <input type="radio" name="feature[]" value="possesion3">
  </td>
  <td> Possesion4
    <input type="radio" name="feature[]" value="possesion4">
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Controller:**

```
function property()
{
  if($_POST)
  {
    $data= array ( 'city' => $_POST['city'], 'location' => $_POST['location'], 'marlas' => $_POST['marlas'] );
    $feature_data = array ( FEATURE_DATA );
    $data['var']= $this->Mdata->p_detail($data,$feature_data);
  }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function p_detail($data,$featuredata){
  $data1 = $this->db->insert('detail',$data);
  $inert_one = $this->db->insert_id();
  $featuredata['property_id'] = $inert_one;
  $feature_data = $this->db->insert('feature_tbl',$featuredata);
  return $insert_one;
}
```

Comment: $insert_one should be insert into property_id in feature table so that i can fetch the feature with respect to the property_id, how i can do this??

Comment: hi pathik vejani , i am getting only one feature with respect to my property detail, but i have multiple feature in my one property detail

Comment: i mean, when i submit the form by checking multiple feature, only one feature add into my feature table,

Comment: how do you get the multiple features?

Comment: I have multiple checkboxes as you can see in my html.

Comment: you have to assign array in form

Comment: then you have to loop the feature and insert into table

Comment: how i can do this help me please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136749/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-harris-khan).

Answer (score 0):

Just make another function in model and call it in controller.

Controller:

```
function property(){

    if($_POST){
    $data_detail = array (
       'city' => $_POST['city'],
       'location' => $_POST['location'],
       'marlas' => $_POST['marlas']
    );

    $data_feature = = array (
       'feature' => $_POST['feature']
    );

    $data['detail_id']= $this->Mdata->p_detail($data_detail );
    $data['feature_id']= $this->Mdata->p_feature($data_feature, $data['detail_id'] );
    }   

}
```

Model:

```
function p_detail($data){
    $this->db->insert('detail',$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

function p_feature($data, $detail_id){
    $data['property_id'] = $detail_id;
    $this->db->insert('feature',$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: i want to make some relation between my tables so that i can match the features of my property while fetching, in this way i cannot grab the features of property

Comment: In details_table, there is a foreign key feature_id am I right?

Comment: Just past the returned value of $data['detail_id'] in controller to the second parameter of $data['feature_id'] then add $data['property_id'] in model. Please check my changes in controller and model.